# Primality of $2^{255}-19$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, primality-test

I need a test for primality that I apply to $2^{255}-19$ (which is claimed to be prime) and certify to be correct with the ACL2 theorem prover.  This means that I must be able to code the test in Common LISP, run it on this case in a reasonable period of time (I'd be happy if it ran in a day), and write a proof of correctness of the test that is simple enough to be mechanized in the ACL2 logic.

Comment: How's your progress?

Answer (score 3):

It takes my C+GMP code under 0.4s to do a BLS75 theorem 5 proof on the number, so this seems like the easiest option.  This involves finding some small factors of p-1, checking conditions, then verifying primality of each factor (note you don't need to factor p-1 completely).  This example has lots of small factors, and the large resulting prime minus 1 factors easily, and so does the next one, with the final value being small enough to check with deterministic M-R or BPSW.

You may be able to use one of the earlier theorems, e.g. 3, which is slightly easier.  I didn't check whether it could trivially do the whole chain by itself.

Using ECPP plus n-1 and n+1 finishes in about 0.01 seconds on my laptop, but that's a lot more coding.  The BLS75-T3 or -T5 would be much easier to code.

BLS75:  http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-130/S0025-5718-1975-0384673-1/S0025-5718-1975-0384673-1.pdf

Comment: This is similar to but slightly less efficient than BLS75-T3:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test#Generalized_Pocklington_method
T3 requires a little less factoring, T5 requires a lot less.  I don't think it matters for your example.  Verifying these certificates is very, very fast -- you do some trivial range checks then compare the results of two modular exponentiations to N-1.  Creating the cert is more time consuming as you have to do some partial factoring, but your example is easy.

Comment: If you have time, could you look at this https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/111016/18298 ?

Answer (score 0):

This very small program written in PARI/GP shows the result and the time
  needed for calculation. I have done this multiple times and the times the
  program needed, differed, but it took never longer than $200ms$. The routine
  certifies the primality using the adleman-pomerance-rumely-test (APR-test),
  which is one of the fastest known algorithms for certifying primes.

```
? gettime();print(isprime(2^255-19,2));gettime()
1
%1 = 110
?
```

Asymptotically, there must be a better algorithm because it is now known,
  that the decision problem : "Is a given natural number $n>1$ prime" is in
  $P$, that means, it can be solved in polnomial time.

Comment: It takes 27ms for me, and mpz_aprcl is similar.  AKS is polynomial time, but the crossover vs. APR-CL is significantly past than the lifetime of our sun, making it of theoretical interest only.  Neither algorithm gives a certificate, making this not very useful for the question.  However, Pari/GP does do Pocklington proofs, similar but a little less efficient than BLS75 theorem 3, and returns certificates.  This number takes about 1100ms for Pari.  My N-1 method takes 300ms, and ECPP takes 12ms.  The N-1 methods (Pocklington, BLS75-T3, BLS75-T5) are appropriate for the OP.